# Qt - Not correctly adding widgets to QHBoxLayout after clearing the layout

Tags: qt

I have a QHBoxLayout in which I added some widgets. I need to be able to refresh the layout dynamically so I use this to clear the layout :

```
void ClearLayout(QLayout* layout)
{
    if (!layout)
        return;

    QLayoutItem* item;
    while ((item = layout->takeAt(0)) != nullptr)
    {
        delete item->widget();
        ClearLayout(item->layout());
    }
}
```

This indeed removes all widgets and layouts. After this `layout->isEmpty()` returns `true` and `layout->count()` returns `0`.

However, when I try to add new widgets (same type of other previously added but new instance) It does not work !

```
AddWidget()
{
    // DeviceWidget inherits QWidget
    DeviceWidget* deviceWidget = new DeviceWidget;
    deviceWidget->setFixedSize(150, 200);

    connect(deviceWidget->GetSignalObject(), &DeviceObject::Selected, this, 
        &DeviceLayout::SelectedDevice);

    layout->addWidget(deviceWidget, 0, Qt::AlignCenter);
}
```

This is the same function used previously to add the widgets to the layout and worked the first time at Construction:

```
MainLayout(QWidget* parent) : QHBoxLayout(parent)
{
    layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    addLayout(layout);

    uint32 nb = GetDeviceNumber(); // returns 2
    for (uint32 i = 0; i < deviceNb; ++i)
        AddDeviceWidget();
}
```

After trying to add 2 widgets I have `layout->isEmpty()` returns `true` and `layout->count()` returns `2` so I'm confused …

[image: Console Output]

thanks for any help provided :)

**EDIT:**

The problem seems to be comming from my DeviceWidget class since trying to add a simple QLabel to the cleared layout worked. Here's the DeviceWidget Constructor:

```
DeviceWidget::DeviceWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout* vLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

    QLabel* deviceIcon = new QLabel("DeviceIcon", this);
    deviceIcon->setFixedSize(128, 128);
    deviceIcon->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage("Resources/Icons/device.png")));
    deviceIcon->setObjectName("DeviceIcon");

    // StatusWidget inherits QWidget
    // Just override paintEvent to display a colored filled disk
    m_status = new StatusWidget(20, Status::Close, this);
    m_status->setObjectName("DeviceStatus");

    vLayout->addWidget(deviceIcon, 0, Qt::AlignCenter);
    vLayout->addWidget(m_status, 0, Qt::AlignCenter);

    // DeviceObjct inherits from QObject an add a signal
    m_object = new DeviceObject(size());

    // Function clearing the stylesheet background-color
    Clear();

    setLayout(vLayout);
    installEventFilter(this);
    setObjectName(QString("DeviceWidget"));
}
```

Commenting `installEventFilter(this)` make it work so I think I need to add an event filter to make it work but I don't know which one

Comment: "_However, when I try to add new widgets it does not work_". Hi there, please include a [mcve] in your question with how you're trying to add new widgets.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I edited the post by adding the function used to add widgets to the layout

Comment: Please show the .ui and .h and .cpp file (stripped down to the minimum required to reproduce your problem).

Comment: I'm only coding on VS with no Qt tool so I don't have .ui file.

Comment: I once wrote an answer to [SO: Does deleting layout deletes its sublayouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53173485/7478597). Not sure whether it addresses your actual problem but, may be, it helps.

Comment: Are you aware that `StatusWidget` is added to parent of `DeviceWidget`? Shouldn't it be added to `this` instead? If you delete `DeviceWidget` the `m_status` is lost but still the instance of `StatusWidget` is child of the parent of `this` deleted `DeviceWidget`. (It might be intended to create a co-widget but I feel a bit "sick" about this.)

Comment: Concerning `installEventFilter(this)`: What is the intention to install an instance as it's own event filter? Instead, you could easily override every intended event handler (which might call the base class event handler and add custom behavior prior or after base class event handling).

Comment: I just realized the same issue for `QLabel` like I did above for `QStatusWidget`...

Comment: @Scheff About StatusWidget and QLabel I agree it was a copy-pasta mistake, thanks for pointing it out! 
About event filter I use it to handle click/enter/leave event, it the first time I handle event like that so that's how I did it but it's probably better the way you said it. 
Also, I succeded in making it work by puting the eventFilter in m_object and calling installEventFilter(m_object). I'll try overriding only enterEvent/leaveEvent/mouseEvent and see if this is better before posting the answer

Comment: To give you a start [`QWidget::enterEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enterEvent). You find the other events in links or close to this.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the Edit, The problem is coming from `DeviceWidget` added in the layout that override `eventFilter`. There is probably a way to add a case in `eventFilter` to make it work but in my case it was best either **(1)** or **(2)**:

**1.** Remove `eventFilter` from `class DeviceWidget` and put it in `class DeviceObject`: m_object is present to emit a signal according to event:

DeviceObject.h:

```
DeviceObject(QObject* parent);
bool eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event) override;

signals:
    void Select(uint32 i);
```

Then in `class DeviceWidget` still call `installEventFilter` but with m_object as parameter: `installEventFilter(m_object);`

For the other event (Enter/Leave) I overrode `void enterEvent(QEvent* event)` and `void leaveEvent(QEvent* event)` for `class DeviceWidget`. That's what lead me to the second option that seems better.

**2.** Completely remove `eventFilter` and `installEventFilter` as it is only used to emit a signal when widget is clicked and do things when cursor hovers the widget. Instead override `enterEvent` and `leaveEvent` for `class DeviceWidget` like said before for hover event.

Then in `class DeviceObjecy` override `void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)` for clicked event.